# RecognizeWithUIAsync cannot use await operator

Tags: windows-phone-8, speech-recognition

I downloaded VS 2013 for Windows and started a new Windows Phone Silverlight application, placed a button and tried to make the example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206966(v=vs.105).aspx) work, but couldn't because of the await operator:

[image]

The examples on the official MSDN site are pretty straight forward, some are like three lines and I can't find anything on the matter. What gives?

Comment: Did you read the exception message? Did you try to do what it said?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `async` to your method to be able to use `await` into it:

`private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`

Comment: oh THAT method.... I thought the message was talking about the RecognizeWithUIAsync() method... Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is self-explanatory, you need to mark your method as async:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```